# Opposite of trim in Python

Tags: python-3.x, trim

I've started learning Python and I was wondering if there is a way to do the opposite of `trim()` in Python. For example I have string:
  `"Need some help around here"` and I want it to become `" Need some help around here "`?

Comment: Note that string trimming generally removes any leading and trailing whitespace. You can add some of your own back, but there's no way to know what was there originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `strip()` removes all the space in the head and tail.
But you can

```
' %s ' % 'Need some help around here'
```

Comment: So if I do `' ' % 'mystring' % ' '` that will translate to `' mystring '`? EDIT: Nevermind I got it it worked out perfectly as you showed , thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `' ' + 'mystring' + ' '`?  `' %s ' % str` fotmats the str.

Comment: yea yea I got cofused for a while but I tested it in online interpreter and now I got it , thanks :)